# chekedlistbox и VScrollBar как их связать?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такой chekedlistbox, как мне сделать прокрутку(так как данных м.б. больше). И можно ли как то прикрепить VScrollBar внутрь chekedlistbox, чтоб меняя расположение chekedlistbox менялось и расположение VScrollBar на форме.

Comment: Так ведь Scrollbar появляется автоматически?